# How to count instances in SQL

Tags: sql, count

I have a table like:

[image]

But I want to count the instances of my duplicate id's:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use `row_number` if your dbms supports it.

Comment: In your desired result, how do the `x1` and `x2` columns relate to the `id` and `id.count` columns? I can't see any clear relationship

Comment: @phil one row is an interaction for a unique id.

Comment: please add the dbms type you actually use in the tags because syntax options differ a lot between dbms vendors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be the syntax in MSSQL

```
 CREATE TABLE #test(id int , x1 int, x2 int)

 INSERT INTO #test(id,x1,x2) VALUES (1,1,1), (2,1,1), (2,2,2);

 SELECT id
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id)
        ,x1 
        ,x2
 FROM #test
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ROW_NUMBER() function

```
SELECT id,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS idcnt,
       x1,
       x2
  FROM tablename
```